# Truncated text in a variable-width container

Tags: html, css

I want to have a two-column list of items where the right column has a fixed width, and the left column is determined by the window size, with its text truncated:

```
+----------------------+-----------+
|Variable width text...|Fixed width|
+----------------------+-----------+
```

All of the examples I've found on how to do truncated text in HTML/CSS use a fixed width for the truncated text, so they don't work for my variable-width case. I usually end up with the left text not being truncated, causing the element to be wider than it should be.

I'd include sample code, but I've tried so many different things I don't know which wrong approach to post :)

This is for a WebView in a desktop application, so I only need it to work with the latest WebKit.

Comment: Truncated as in word wrap or really just gone?

Comment: And if you want the three dots, google "jquery ellipsis"

Comment: Yes, I'm going for the ellipsis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you really want to text to be truncated you could do something like: http://jsfiddle.net/fju9q/2/

Which uses 2 `div`s. The right `div` is floated and the left `div` uses `overflow: hidden` and `white-space: nowrap;` to make sure the text is truncated.

Comment: That gets me most of the way there. My next problem is that this is inside a table, and the `td` seems to be calculating its width based on the pre-truncated text - http://jsfiddle.net/Q3AbF/

Comment: Aha, I've got it now. I  just needed `table-layout: fixed`. Thanks!